# Maximum Number of Files Per User Per Day

Tags: file-upload

I'm currently working in a SharePoint dev environment and my problem is that sometimes I am ableto upload and sometimes (after a few successful uploads and usually happens EOD) I am not.

My question really is is there a maximum upload limit (not the size but the actual number of uploaded files) per user per day?

Comment: What does EOD stand for?

Comment: End of day. It usually happens by the end of the day.

Comment: Ah of course, I was expecting it to be something technical!

Comment: Did I do something wrong? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of files that can be uploaded but it is possible that you are hitting other limitations, such as available disk space on the SharePoint or Database Servers or maximum DB size in the databases themselves (or other DB limits if using SQL Express).  My suggestion would be for you to watch for when this happens and then scour the Event Logs and the HIVE/LOGS folder for specifics on the actual underlying error.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow your instructions and get back with the results. Thank you.

Comment: Dave, all I saw in the logs are login failed events and this: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: Try restarting the machine.  If that doesn't work then it is possible that you have a dying RAM chip